# Teamviewer does not work unless I open application

Tags: teamviewer

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 running Teamviewer v15.8.3. Teamviewer does not work unless I open the program manually (even though startup with system is enabled) which defeats the purpose of the program since I only use this system remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's TV issue working with Ubuntu.  I was fine on TV v15.0.8 + Ubuntu 19 until I upgraded to Ubuntu 20 + TV 5.12.  TV only works when I login on the semi-remote box.

I switched to VNC.  All is well now.